# Cannot read find of undefined (fancybox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

I have View with some kind of gallery

Here is code of it

```
 <div class="image_wrap">
  <a class="fancybox_43566 thumb_a" href="https://******.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/003/623/222/LON-91B-1.jpg?1387213390">
    <div class="image">
      <div class="resize-and-crop" style="width: 250px; height: 200px;"><img alt="Exterior" src="https://*******.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/003/623/222/LON-91B-1.jpg?1387213390" width="250" height="250" class="big_thumb" style="left: 0px; top: -25px;"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="other_images">
      <div class="small_image">
        <a class="fancybox_43566" href="https://******.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/003/623/222/LON-91B-1.jpg?1387213390">
          <div class="resize-and-crop" style="width: 60px; height: 40px;"><img alt="Exterior" src="https://*****.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/003/623/222/LON-91B-1.jpg?1387213390" width="60" height="60" class="small_thumb_img" style="left: 0px; top: -10px;"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="small_image">
        <a class="fancybox_43566" href="https://*******.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/003/623/225/LON-91B-2.jpg?1387213390">
          <div class="resize-and-crop" style="width: 60px; height: 40px;"><img alt="Lobby" src="https://******.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/003/623/225/LON-91B-2.jpg?1387213390" width="60" height="45" class="small_thumb_img" style="left: 0px; top: -3px;"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="small_image">
        <a class="fancybox_43566" href="https://********.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/003/623/227/LON-91B-3.jpg?1387213390">
          <div class="resize-and-crop" style="width: 60px; height: 40px;"><img alt="Lobby" src="https://*******.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/003/623/227/LON-91B-3.jpg?1387213390" width="60" height="45" class="small_thumb_img" style="left: 0px; top: -3px;"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="small_image">
        <a class="fancybox_43566" href="https://*******.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/003/623/230/LON-91B-4.jpg?1387213391">
          <div class="resize-and-crop" style="width: 60px; height: 40px;"><img alt="Lobby" src="https://*******.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/003/623/230/LON-91B-4.jpg?1387213391" width="60" height="45" class="small_thumb_img" style="left: 0px; top: -3px;"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="small_image">
        <a class="fancybox_43566" href="https://*******.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/003/623/232/LON-91B-5.jpg?1387213391">
          <div class="resize-and-crop" style="width: 60px; height: 40px;"><img alt="Guest Room" src="https://******.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/003/623/232/LON-91B-5.jpg?1387213391" width="60" height="45" class="small_thumb_img" style="left: 0px; top: -3px;"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need on click on image open fancybox gallery

So in Rails View I have this code

```
<%= javascript_tag "$('.fancybox_#{hotel.id}').attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({ prevEffect : 'none', nextEffect : 'none', closeBtn : true, beforeShow : function() { var alt = this.element.find('img').attr('alt'); this.inner.find('img').attr('alt', alt); this.title = alt; }, helpers : { title : { type : 'inside' }} });" %>
```

But when I click image I get this error.

> > Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
> >         at Object.beforeShow (:3:164)
> >         at FancyBox.trigger (jquery.fancybox.js:2669)
> >         at FancyBox.jumpTo (jquery.fancybox.js:1058)
> >         at FancyBox.init (jquery.fancybox.js:608)
> >         at new FancyBox (jquery.fancybox.js:514)
> >         at Object.open (jquery.fancybox.js:2803)
> >         at HTMLAnchorElement._run (jquery.fancybox.js:3048)
> >         at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (event.js:340)
> >         at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (event.js:148)
> >         at HTMLAnchorElement.fn.___hb (honeybadger.js:399)

At this part of script tag `this.element.find('img').attr('alt'); this.inner.find('img').attr('alt', alt); this.title = alt;`

Where can be my problem?

Comment: `this.element` and/or `this.inner` is undefined in the `beforeShow` event handler.I'd suggest using the console to determine which

Comment: How I can do this? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: `console.log(this)` in the event handler

Comment: console.log(this) in beforeShow function gets this:

`{src: "https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/003/623/227/LON-91B-3.jpg?1387213390", opts: {…}, type: "image", contentType: "image", index: 0, …}` @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: You need to expand it and check what the values of `element` and `inner` are - if there are even present

Comment: Nope it not have `element` @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: There's your problem then. I'd suggest you double check with the documentation to see if there's another way to get the element which raised the event as what you're doing now won't work.

Answer (score 0):

So here is answer

Because I have not has element and inner, code will be like this

```
  $('.fancybox_#{hotel.id}').attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({ prevEffect : 'none', nextEffect : 'none', closeBtn : true, beforeShow : function() { var alt = this.src; this.title = alt; }, helpers : { title : { type : 'inside' }} });
```

I just use src in beforeShow metod and it works